# How to install package on fedora under live session?

Tags: fedora

I accidentally uninstalled gnome from my fedora installation and now I got only terminal when I switch my computer on. Moreover, my WiFi card is damaged and I can't get it correctly configured.

But when I start the laptop from fedora live CD, I get full access to my computer with gui. Now, I would like to reinstall lxde from there. How can I do it ?

Comment: erm...how is that the user does not exist here? Does the migration only work for the question but not for the user who asked (if he/she is not member of the target community)?

Comment: @dave_alcarin My guess is that SE allows the user to choose not to join a community.

Answer (score 2):

Mount your system in the live session, `chroot` to it and run the usual installation commands from there, `sudo yum install lxde` in your case.